# simple json library for decode json string in java

Tags: java, json, web-services

Hi I am new to using the json-simple library in Java, i would like to decode this json string.now i want vendor id from the json string. you can find my code bellow;

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns2:getCategoriesbyVendorIDResponse xmlns:ns2="http://Innovation/">
      <return>
        {"Head":"CategoryId":"103","CategoryName":"Lenovajhkjb","VendorId":"125"}]}}
      </return>
    </ns2:getCategoriesbyVendorIDResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: try google for `java json library`

Comment: I want vendor id from the json string so now i want to write java code for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [json](http://www.json.org/java/) library

`{`->represent the jsonobject
`[`->represent the jsonArray

```
JSONObject jobject=new JSONObject(jsonstring);
JSONObject head=jobject.getJSONObject("Head");
String vendorid=head.getString("VendorId");
```

Comment: Here i'm getting an error why because the above code is for json decoding but it is not getting directly from the result this json result is in XML string get Categories by Vendor ID Response

Comment: i want code for xml parsing also along with json parsing

Comment: so for that you need to parse the xml first and get the string and put inside the jsonobject

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Powerful and easy to use library.

Comment: It is, but the OP seems to be married to the idea of using a library called 'json-simple', probably because it has the word 'simple' in the name.